# How to display pictures from shared OneDrive folder on the Windows 8.1 lock screen?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I would like one machine to show a photo slide show on the lock screen, with photos belonging to another Microsoft account.

I have shared the "Camera Roll" album from the photo producers account to the receiver, and can see the photos as shared to the receiver on OneDrive online. But on Windows 8.1, when choosing what folders to include in the slide show - there's only the option to select folders created by the user - not the folders shared to the user.

Can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From @thurrott via twitter:

> @andyhammar You can't. Shared photos are a big weakness of all the
>   OneDrive clients right now